# Divs not aligned to top

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, css-calc

Why this is happening? I need someone who can explain why divs not aligning properly?

HTML and CSS:

```css
.horizontal-ruler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #373737;
}
.horizontal-ruler .ruler-unit {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.h-ruler-first-line,
.h-ruler-second-line {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
  margin: 12px 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #373737;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-ruler">
  <div class="h-ruler-first-line"></div><!--
--><div class="ruler-unit">24"</div><!--
--><div class="h-ruler-second-line"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6xuvr6vw/1/

As you can see the `.ruler-unit` is not contained into the `.horizontal-ruler`.

Comment: "vertical-align: middle" is missing on this selector .h-ruler-first-line

Comment: @RazvanCuceu : could you please acknowledge the answers below if they helped you? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to the lines:

```
.h-ruler-first-line, .h-ruler-second-line {
    width: calc(50% - 15px);
    margin: 12px 0;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #373737;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/udwffajo/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `vertical-align: middle` to lines also

```css
.horizontal-ruler {
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #373737;
}

.horizontal-ruler .ruler-unit {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.h-ruler-first-line,
.h-ruler-second-line {
  width: calc(50% - 15px);
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 12px 0;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #373737;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-ruler">
  <div class="h-ruler-first-line"></div><!--
--><div class="ruler-unit">24"</div><!--
--><div class="h-ruler-second-line"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it with just 2 `div` elements using `:after` and `:before` pseudo elements.

```css
.horizontal-ruler{
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #373737;
  height: 25px;
}
.horizontal-ruler .ruler-unit {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.horizontal-ruler .ruler-unit:before,
.horizontal-ruler .ruler-unit:after {
  background-color: #373737;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -1px;
  width: 9999px;
  height: 1px;
  right: 100%;
  content: '';
  top: 50%;
}
.horizontal-ruler .ruler-unit:after {
  right: auto;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-ruler">
  <div class="ruler-unit">24"</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly different approach to your solution -this features a border bottom on the entire div and the a relative position of the text down over the line to give the appearance that it is two line separated by the text content. Could probably be better - just dodgied it up to show you an alternative that does not take much code to achieve the same effect.

```css
.horizontal-ruler{
  border-bottom:solid 1px #373737;
  text-align:center;
}
.ruler-unit{
  font-size:24px;
  width:30px;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
  position:relative;
  top:14px;
  background:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="horizontal-ruler">
<div class="ruler-unit">24"</div>
</div>
```